# Factor to Month-Year Conversion in R

Tags: r, date, data-conversion

Have a factor column as `April-2017` `February-2017` etc. Want to convert it to Month and Year to order the column as per the month and year so that it start from January. Tried following:

```
Combi$Month <- as.yearmon(levels(Combined$Month))[Combined$Month] -> Yields 'NA'
Combined$Month <- as.Date(Combined$Month,'%B-%Y') -> Yields 'NA'
```

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"yearmon"` class can represent year-month and sorts as expected:

```
library(zoo)
x <- factor(c('April-2017', 'February-2017')) # test data

ym <- as.yearmon(x, "%B-%Y")
sort(ym)
## [1] "Feb 2017" "Apr 2017"
```

Because of this you don't really need to convert it to `"Date"` class nor do you need the year and month separately but if for some reason not stated in the question you still do need separate values then `as.integer(ym)` and `cycle(ym)` give the years as 4 digit numbers and the months as numbers between 1 and 12.  Also `as.Date(ym)` gives `"Date"` class values.

Answer (score 2):

An R base way:

```
# Some sample data
df <- data.frame(period=sample(c("April-2017","February-2017"),10, replace = TRUE))

nicep <- function(x) {
    months <- c('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December')
    l <- strsplit(x, '-')
    return(sprintf("%s-%02d",l[[1]][2], which(months == l[[1]][1])))
}

# change levels for a nice name
levels(df$period) <- unlist(lapply(as.character(levels(df$period)), FUN=nicep))
```